# Working with optional JSON fields in Rust, avoid None / null in JSON, use undefined instead

Tags: json, rust, serde

is there a better (leaner) way to express my self other than this:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Default]
pub struct PagingObject {
  #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
  offsetId: Option<String>,     // offset expressed as element id (uuid)
  #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
  offset: Option<i32>,          // offset expressed as index (numeric)
  #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
  total: Option<i32>,           // total number of elements
  #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
  totalPages: Option<i32>,      // total number of pages based on limit
  #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
  previous: Option<String>,     // link to previous page
  #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
  next: Option<String>,         // link to next page
  #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
  limit: Option<i32>            // the limit used
}
```

Comment: yikes, that looks like python dataclasses but slightly worse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

serde does not have any built-in way on dealing with this. However, the third-party [`serde_with::skip_serializing_none`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/attr.skip_serializing_none.html) macro addresses this problem. The usage is as simple as adding another attribute before the derive.

```rust
#[serde_with::skip_serializing_none]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Default]
pub struct PagingObject {
  offsetId: Option<String>,     // offset expressed as element id (uuid)
  offset: Option<i32>,          // offset expressed as index (numeric)
  total: Option<i32>,           // total number of elements
  totalPages: Option<i32>,      // total number of pages based on limit
  previous: Option<String>,     // link to previous page
  next: Option<String>,         // link to next page
  limit: Option<i32>            // the limit used
}
```

Comment: This is nice, directly to the tools bag!

Comment: in the json case, add

`
[dependencies.serde_with]
version = "1.12.1"
features = [ "json" ]
`

to your Cargo.toml

Comment: @wzr You do not need `features = [ "json" ]`. You only need the `macros` feature, which is enabled by default.
https://docs.rs/serde_with/1.12.1/serde_with/guide/feature_flags/index.html#json