# Is there any way to remove None fields in a struct serialized with serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I am trying to get User info from MongoDB like this:

```rust
pub async fn find_user_by_name(&self, data: String) -> Vec<Uye> {
    let filter = doc! {"isim": data};
    let options = FindOptions::builder()
        .projection(doc! {"sifre": 0, "mail": 0, "tokenInfo": 0 })
        .build();
    let cursor = match self.user_col.find(None, options).await {
        std::result::Result::Ok(cursor) => cursor,
        std::result::Result::Err(_) => return vec![],
    };

    cursor.try_collect().await.unwrap()
}
```

My Uye struct is:

```rust
pub struct Uye {
    pub id: Option<i32>,
    pub isim: Option<String>,
    pub sifre: Option<String>,
    pub mail: Option<String>,
    pub dogumtarihi: Option<String>,
    pub avatar_url: Option<String>,
    pub kaydedilen: Option<Vec<i32>>,
    pub perm: Option<String>,
    pub permLevel: Option<i32>,
    pub onaylandi: Option<bool>,
    pub isDummy: Option<bool>,
    pub hesap_onay_kodu: Option<i32>,
    pub avatar_path: Option<String>,
    pub tokenInfo: Option<TokenInfo>,
}
```

When I get the data from the API with http request, the result is like this:

```json
{
  "status": "basarili",
  "user": [
    {
      "id": 60,
      "isim": "test User",
      "sifre": null, // <-----
      "mail": null, // <-----
      "dogumtarihi": "",
      "avatar_url": "/static/uploads/images/avatar",
      "kaydedilen": [],
      "perm": "Üye",
      "permLevel": 0,
      "onaylandi": false,
      "isDummy": false,
      "hesap_onay_kodu": 123123,
      "avatar_path": "/static/uploads/images/avatar",
      "tokenInfo": null // <-----
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to delete null fields from object to make it look more better. Is there any way to it ?

Comment: Hm. [Duplicate-ish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71827811/working-with-optional-json-fields-in-rust-avoid-none-null-in-json-use-undefi/71828331#71828331)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working with optional JSON fields in Rust, avoid None / null in JSON, use undefined instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71827811/working-with-optional-json-fields-in-rust-avoid-none-null-in-json-use-undefi)

Answer (score 6):

You have quite a lot of fields in your struct. Might be worthwhile to use the [`serde_with`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/2.0.0/serde_with/attr.skip_serializing_none.html) crate:

```
#[serde_with::skip_serializing_none]
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Uye {
    pub id: Option<i32>,
    pub isim: Option<String>,
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The crate is called serde_with. `serde_as` is another macro in the crate. But the link is correct :)

Comment: Thank you, fixed. (I can never remember which it is. Apparently not even for 5 seconds.)

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it with serde skip seriliazing...

more info: https://serde.rs/attr-skip-serializing.html

Fixed struct:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct Uye {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub id: Option<i32>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub isim: Option<String>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub sifre: Option<String>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub mail: Option<String>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub dogumtarihi: Option<String>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub avatar_url: Option<String>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub kaydedilen: Option<Vec<i32>>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub perm: Option<String>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub permLevel: Option<i32>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub onaylandi: Option<bool>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub isDummy: Option<bool>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub hesap_onay_kodu: Option<i32>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub avatar_path: Option<String>,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub tokenInfo: Option<TokenInfo>,
}
```